# нужна помощь в парсе json в андроид преложении

Tags: android, json, парсер

вот сервер с которого я получаю json:
http://getshexml.azurewebsites.net/Client.svc/getClientsjson

```
MainActivity{
String json = "[\"{\\\"phone\\\": \\\"380554\\\", \\\"fio\\\": \\\"VLAD ZAECH\\\",\\\"about\\\":\\\"BASTARD BAD PM\\\"}\",\"{\\\"phone\\\": \\\"38065664\\\", \\\"fio\\\": \\\"Nastya\\\",\\\"about\\\":\\\"BEST PM EVER\\\"}\",\"{\\\"phone\\\": \\\"123456789123\\\", \\\"fio\\\": \\\"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\\",\\\"about\\\":\\\"\\\"}\",\"{\\\"phone\\\": \\\"\\\", \\\"fio\\\": \\\"\\\",\\\"about\\\":\\\"Who is it?\\\"}\"]";

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();

    Type datasetListType = new TypeToken<Collection<DataDTO>>() {
    }.getType();
    Log.d("MyLog", "тут вылетит");
    List<DataDTO> data = gson.fromJson(json, datasetListType);
    Log.d("MyLog", "не вылетело");

    for (DataDTO dataset : data) {
        Log.d("MyLog", dataset.getPhone());
        Log.d("MyLog", dataset.getFio());
        Log.d("MyLog", dataset.getAbout());
    }
}

DataDTO{
private String phone;
private String fio;
private String about;

public DataDTO() {

}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {

    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getFio() {
    return fio;
}

public void setFio(String fio) {
    this.fio = fio;
}

public String getAbout() {
    return about;
}

public void setAbout(String about) {
    this.about = about;
}
```

на логе вылетело он вылетает
подскажите что не так и скажите какой нибудь литературы для работы с сервером в андроид и парсом json

Comment: стактрейс где ?

Comment: Спасибо значить я не один думаю что это карявый json.А да кстати я нашел отличное решение как пропарсить это все если исправить json 'код' Type datasetListType = new TypeToken<Collection<DataDTO>>() {
        }.getType();

        List<DataDTO> data = gson.fromJson(json, datasetListType);

Answer (score 0):

кароче json оказался кривым спасибо @metalurgus. для парса кода воспользовался вот этим примером: http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-serializing-collections.jsp